# MFC BitBlt and SetDIBits vs. SetBitmapBits

Tags: c++, bitmap, mfc, bitblt, dib

I have a bitmap stored as a BGRA array of bytes. This is the code I've been using to paint the bitmap:

```
CDC *dispDC = new CDC();
dispDC->CreateCompatibleDC(pDC);
CBitmap *dispBMP = new CBitmap();
dispBMP->CreateCompatibleBitmap(pDC, sourceImage->GetWidth(), sourceImage->GetHeight());
dispDC->SelectObject(this->dispBMP);
```

The actual copying of the pixels in the `translatedImage` array happens with this:

```
dispBMP->SetBitmapBits(sourceImage->GetArea() * 4, translatedImage);
```

Then after some more processing I call `pDC->StretchBlt` with `dispDC` as the source CDC. This works fine when logged in locally because the display is also set to 32bpp.

Once I log in with Remote Desktop, the display goes to 16bpp and the image is mangled. The culprit is `SetBitmapBits`; i.e. for it to work, I have to properly fill `translatedImage` with the 16bpp version of what I want to show. Rather than do this myself, I searched the documentation and found `SetDIBits` which sounds like it does what I want:

> The SetDIBits function sets the pixels in a compatible bitmap (DDB) using the color data found in the specified DIB.

In my case, the DIB is the 32bpp RGBA array, and the DDB is `dispBMP` which I create with `CreateCompatibleBitmap`.

So instead of my call to `SetBitmapBits`, this is what I did:

```
BITMAPINFO info;
ZeroMemory(&info, sizeof(BITMAPINFO));
info.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
info.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
info.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
info.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
info.bmiHeader.biSizeImage = sourceImage->GetArea()*4;
info.bmiHeader.biWidth = sourceImage->GetWidth();
info.bmiHeader.biHeight = sourceImage->GetHeight();
info.bmiHeader.biClrUsed = 0;

int r = SetDIBits(pDC->GetSafeHdc(), (HBITMAP)dispBMP,
                  0, sourceImage->GetHeight(), translatedImage, 
                  &info, DIB_PAL_COLORS);
```

However, `r` is always zero and, naturally, I get nothing but black in my window. What is wrong with the code?

Comment: Have you checked input of `SetDIBits`, when you log in with Remote Desktop? For example, is it true, that `dispBMP!=NULL` in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ross Ridge was correct in pointing out the code order mistake. However, this didn't solve the problem.

The problem was in the parameters I was passing. I am new to C++ and MFC and often forget all the "operators" which can act on types to automatically convert them.

Previously I had this:

```
int r = SetDIBits(pDC->GetSafeHdc(), (HBITMAP)dispBMP,
              0, sourceImage->GetHeight(), translatedImage, 
              &info, DIB_PAL_COLORS);
```

The correct call is this:

```
int r = SetDIBits(*pDC, *dispBMP,
              0, sourceImage->GetHeight(), translatedImage, 
              &info, DIB_PAL_COLORS);
```

(Note I pass dereferenced pointers in the first two parameters.) Everything else was correct, including the counter-intuitive `DIB_PAL_COLORS` flag for a bitmap which has not palette.

After obviously missing some key points in the documentation I reread it and then found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms969901.aspx) which has sample code showing that I was simply passing the parameters incorrectly.

Comment: There was nothing wrong with the `GetSafeHdc` you were using, the problem was in casting the pointer to CBitmap `dispBMP` rather than the object itself `*dispBMP`. I'm curious why you made it a pointer in the first place rather than a local object?

Comment: @MarkRansom: `dispBMP` is a class member variable because I have found in my experience with C that allocating memory ends up often time being very expensive in the types of application I work on (data processing). So since this is a new project starting from scratch I'm being very careful to reuse large memory objects like bitmaps and bitmap byte arrays.

Comment: That strategy isn't buying you much in this case. Do a `sizeof(dispBMP)` to see what I mean - it doesn't *contain* the bitmap, it holds a *handle* to the bitmap, which is allocated separately.

Comment: @MarkRansom: right. So if I lose that handle I need to create a new bitmap every time. Isn't `CreateCompatibleBitmap` the one allocating the memory? I don't show it in my snippet, but in the actual code I only call that if I know the image changed size or if `dispBMP` is `NULL`.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [documentation for `SetDIBits`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162973.aspx):

> The bitmap identified by the hbmp parameter must not be selected into a
>   device context when the application calls this function.

In your example code you select it into device context after creating it, so presumably that's why `SetDIBits` is failing.

Comment: This is not the reason, apparently. I now have the `SelectObject` call just before the `StretchBLT` call with `SetDIBits` in between and still get black. `SetDIBits` returns zero and obviously does nothing because if I leave both it and the `SetBitmapBits` call, I get the proper image (until I go into remote desktop).